# Take photos in rapid succession on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, webcam, photos

I have a MacBook with running Snow Leopard. Is there a way that allows me to take rapid fire photos with the camera?

PhotoBooth sort of has this feature, but it only takes 4, and they are combined into one big image.

Comment: [This post on AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18160/how-do-i-take-a-steathy-picture-with-my-isight-camera-from-the-command-line) should work for you.  But I am not on my mac and can't test it out.  Another option is to write a python script for it using Pygame or OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download imagesnap with `brew install imagesnap` or from http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/ and run something like this in a terminal:

```
i=1; while :; do /path/to/imagesnap ~/Desktop/$((i++)).png; done
```

I use a script like this:

```
while :; do
  i=1
  n=~/Desktop/$(date +%y%m%d%H%M%S)-$i.png
  while [[ -e $n ]]; do
    n=${n%-*}-$((i++)).png
  done
  imagesnap $n
  sleep ${1-0}
done
```